# How to Run two @Test methods in a single class file using webdriver and TestNG

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, testng, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have a piece of code in Web Driver which is as mentioned below. There are two `@Test` methods in a single class which I am trying to execute parallel using `testng.xml`.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here

```
public class CrossBrowserScript {

    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest

    @Parameters("browser")

    public void setup(String browser) throws Exception{

        //Check if parameter passed from TestNG is 'firefox'

        if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")){

        //create firefox instance

            driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        }

        //Check if parameter passed as 'chrome'

        else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")){

            //set path to chromedriver.exe You may need to download it from http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver

            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\Maven\\chromedriver.exe");

            //create chrome instance

            driver = new ChromeDriver();

        }

else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("ie")){

            //set path to IEdriver.exe You may need to download it from

     // 32 bits http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.42/IEDriverServer_Win32_2.42.0.zip

     // 64 bits http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.42/IEDriverServer_x64_2.42.0.zip

            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","E:\\Maven\\IEDriverServer.exe");

            //create chrome instance

            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

        }

        else{

            //If no browser passed throw exception

            throw new Exception("Browser is not correct");

        }

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }    
}

package checking;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class test extends CrossBrowserScript{


    @Parameters({ "browser" })
    @Test
    public void checking_value(){

        //WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.sourcefuse.com/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        if(driver.getPageSource().contains("Our Work"))
        {
            System.out.println("Found the text");
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("Not able to found the text");
        }

    }

    @Parameters({ "browser" })
    @Test
    public void second_method(){


        driver.get("http://www.sourcefuse.com/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        if(driver.getPageSource().contains("Our Work"))
        {
            System.out.println("Found the text");
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("Not able to found the text");
        }

    }

    }

*************************************************************
TestNG.xml File
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="Multiple Tests" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">

    <test name="Test One">

        <parameter name="browser" value="Chrome" />
        <classes>
            <class name="checking.test">

            </class>

        </classes>
    </test>




    <test name="Test two">

        <parameter name="browser" value="Firefox" />
        <classes>
            <class name="checking.test">
            </class>

        </classes>
    </test>

</suite>
```

When I am executing, it is opening 2 browsers and executing the above code total of 4 times but my concern is I want to run two `@Test` in 2 different browsers.

Comment: you are probably getting confuse between what TestNG referes as Test, when you say parallel="tests" it's going to consider all the tests you have mention in **Test One** and **Test two** configuration. Change the configuration to include only specific test rather than whole class and issue might get resolved.

Comment: Hey Gagan can you please let me know what should i write in that case i have searched google but didn't find anything related to it, I want to run @tests of a single class file in multiple browser parallel mode

Comment: Can Anyone Else Help me in this scenario

Comment: Hi Akash, I believe you should rephrase your title. To my understanding, you don't have 2 methods that you want to execute in one class file, but more that you have 2 tests that you want to execute in parallel. I'll post the correct XML as a solution if this is what you are after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to make this work is to stick your 2 methods into 2 different classes both of them extending your CrossBrowserScript  (i.e. testChrome and testFirefox)

Try this in your xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="Multiple Tests" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">

    <test name="Test One">

        <parameter name="browser" value="Chrome" />
        <classes>
            <class name="checking.testChrome">

            </class>

        </classes>
    </test>




    <test name="Test two">

        <parameter name="browser" value="Firefox" />
        <classes>
            <class name="checking.testFirefox">
            </class>

        </classes>
    </test>

</suite>
```

Comment: Your answers is a workaround but not the solution for this question By making 2 different classes for 2 Tests and then executing them in parallel is easy that anyway i know my question is if i want to execute 2 Test from a single class file onto 2 different browser in parallel if this is possible

Comment: Well you can change the parallel="methods" but then I don't think you can use xml params. You will need to handle your browser var progamatically. Best of luck